# SQL Trigger Fires on Every 24 Hrs

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-express

I want to make a MSSQL Trigger which will Fires in Everyday when date will change.

Comment: BTW, there *is* no 12am (or pm). It's either midnight or noon. Today's pedantry was bought to you by the letter `P` and the number `42` :-)

Comment: You mean You want trigger to fire not immidiately, but at 12AM for every record that changed?

Comment: You need JOB not trigger.

Comment: Yes i need trigger  because i have a SQL Express Edition so not able to make job.@Serg

Comment: @paxdiablo, my phone has both 12 AM and 12 PM.

Comment: use sqlcmd and schedule it in windows task scheduler

Comment: @jarlh, then your phone is wrong (must be an Android: pax ducks for cover). By definition, 12:00 (either of them) are neither ante or post meridian.

Comment: @paxdiablo, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock, "Each period consists of 12 hours numbered: 12 (acting as zero), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11. The 24 hour/day cycle starts at 12 midnight (often indicated as 12 a.m.), runs through 12 noon (often indicated as 12 p.m.)".

Comment: @jarlh, did you read *all* of that? Specifically the bit at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, sorry, had no time for that. Went to lunch at 12AM (or was it perhaps 12PM?).

Comment: @KuldipRana have you found solution to your problem?

Comment: @gofr1...Yes... for temporary solution i made one API and i call it from cron website. cron websites is platform where we can run our URLs on given time.

Answer (score 1):

For MSSS Express editions create MS Windows job which will start  Sqlcmd, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx
which will run an Sql script. Note, when sqlcmd is run from the command line, sqlcmd uses the OLE DB provider.

How to create a Sqlcmd job by using Windows Task Scheduler https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698 . This article deals with DB backup task. Replace the Sql script at step A with the one you need and adjust following steps accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.. But how to make job schedule with sqlcmd. please give me link or suggestion if you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **schedule a JOB** in SQL which will fire in defined time and put your query in **JOB**

- Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select 'New Job'.
- In the 'New Job' window enter the name of the job and a description on the 'General' tab.
- Select 'Steps' on the left hand side of the window and click 'New' at the bottom.
- In the 'Steps' window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.
- Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.
- Click on the 'Schedule' menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time).
- Click 'OK' - and that should be it.

Comment: I have SQL Express which not have SQL Server Agent. Any other solution ?

Comment: You can also make one application which timely execute your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use **PowerShell** and **Task Sheduler**. All action below must be done on the machine where SQL Server is running.

At first create `.sql` file with a batch to run. I call it `my_batch.sql`. F.e. with this inside:

```
USE [MyDB]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]
           ([id]
           ,[somevalue]
           ,[New Column]
           ,[NewColumn])
     VALUES
           (NEWID()
           ,'testing'
           ,'test'
           ,'just a test')
```

Do not use `GO` in this script!

Then create `.ps1` script to run that batch file (`my_batch.ps1`):

```
$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$ConnectionString = "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
$conn.Open()

$fileToGetContent = 'D:\my_batch.sql'
$commandText = Get-Content -Path $fileToGetContent

$command = $conn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $commandText
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

$conn.Close()
```

Then create a schedule task. You can make it manually ([here](http://terrytlslau.tls1.cc/2014/08/create-schedule-task-to-run-powershell.html) is a good sample) or via PowerShell (I prefer this way):

```
#Create a new trigger that is configured to trigger at startup
$STTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 00:01

#Name for the scheduled task
$STName = "Run SQL batch"

#Action to run as
$STAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "D:\my_batch.ps1"

#Configure when to stop the task and how long it can run for. In this example it does not stop on idle and uses the maximum possible duration by setting a timelimit of 0
$STSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DontStopOnIdleEnd -ExecutionTimeLimit ([TimeSpan]::Zero)

#Configure the principal to use for the scheduled task and the level to run as 
$STPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -User "DOMAIN\user" -RunLevel "Highest" 

#Register the new scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask $STName -Action $STAction -Trigger $STTrigger -Principal $STPrincipal -Settings $STSettings
```